# EU citizen with a layover in the UK

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers, eu-citizens, brexit

I'm planning a trip to the US this summer, and many of the options I get for my flights have a layover in London. Will I have to go through passport control or will I be able to enter freely as I would with any Schengen country?

Comment: This question is confusing.  "Will I have to go through passport control" is not opposed to "will I be able to enter freely."  The answer to both questions could be "yes."  You will certainly be able to enter freely, but that will only matter if you have to go through passport control.  What exactly are you trying to find out here, and why?  Is it in fact important for some reason to know whether you'll need to go through passport control?

Comment: Hello. My question was whether I would have to go through lengthy passport controls between landing and departing or if I would be able to just walk from one plane to the other as I would do if the layover was in Italy, for example.

Comment: @phoog: You are literally contradicting yourself. The word "control" means the opposite of "freely", and vice versa. If you are controlled then you are not free, and if you are free then you can't be controlled.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a EU passport you are anyway still allowed to freely enter the UK. 
If you are transiting through London on a true connection (ie. both flights on one ticket) at the same airport you do not need to enter the UK. You will make an airside transit in stead.

Comment: *If you are transiting through London on a true connection (ie. both flights on one ticket) you do not need to enter the UK.* This is not true. Some tickets do include interairport transfers (eg Heathrow to Gatwick).

Comment: Correct. Edited my answer. Although why one would voluntarily do this I don't know...

Comment: Thank you. The layover would be in a single airport as far as I've seen.